# Apache FOP Displaying ### instead of Arabic

Tags: pdf-generation, arabic, apache-fop

I am new to Apache-FOP.

I use this to generate PDF documet from a XML input. I have created XSL for my input XML and getting ### values instead of Arabic text. Can any one please point out the mistake? I have set of fonts but still I cannot get the right result.

XML Input:

```
<TestData>
<TestXML>
<Name>Sathish நன்றி</Name>
<Dept>Channels</Dept>
<Year>2016</Year>
</TestXML>
<TestXML>
<Name>Sathish dėkoju</Name>
<Dept>Channels</Dept>
<Year>2016</Year>
</TestXML>
<TestXML>
<Name>Sathish благодаря</Name>
<Dept>Channels</Dept>
<Year>2016</Year>
</TestXML>
<TestXML>
<Name>Sathish شكر</Name>
<Dept>Channels</Dept>
<Year>2016</Year>
</TestXML>
</TestData>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
<fo:root>
<fo:layout-master-set>
<fo:simple-page-master master-name="A4-portrait" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21.0cm" margin="2cm">
<fo:region-body />
</fo:simple-page-master>
</fo:layout-master-set>
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4-portrait">
<fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
<fo:block>
<fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%">
<fo:table-header>
<fo:table-row   background-color="#c0c0c0" height="0.59cm">
<fo:table-cell   number-columns-spanned="1">
<fo:block   margin-left="0.0cm" margin-right="0.14cm"  margin-top="0.0cm"  font-size="10pt"    color="#000000"  text-align="left">Name</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell   number-columns-spanned="1">
<fo:block   margin-left="0.51cm" margin-right="0.16cm"  margin-top="0.0cm"  font-size="10pt"    color="#000000"  text-align="left">Department</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell   number-columns-spanned="1">
<fo:block   margin-left="0.0cm" margin-right="2.65cm"  margin-top="0.0cm"  font-size="10pt"    color="#000000"  text-align="left">Year</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
</fo:table-header>
<fo:table-body>
<xsl:for-each select="TestData/TestXML">
<fo:table-row   background-color="#ffffff" height="0.57cm">
<fo:table-cell   number-columns-spanned="1">
<fo:block   margin-left="0.0cm" margin-right="0.14cm"  margin-top="0.0cm"  font-size="10pt"   color="#000000"  text-align="left">
<xsl:value-of select="Name" />
</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell   number-columns-spanned="1">
<fo:block   margin-left="0.0cm" margin-right="0.14cm"  margin-top="0.0cm"  font-size="10pt"   color="#000000"  text-align="left">
<xsl:value-of select="Dept" />
</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell   number-columns-spanned="1">
<fo:block   margin-left="0.0cm" margin-right="0.14cm"  margin-top="0.0cm"  font-size="10pt"   color="#000000"  text-align="left">
<xsl:value-of select="Year" />
</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>                            
</fo:table-row>
</xsl:for-each>
</fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
</fo:block>
</fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

myConf.xconf:

```
<fop> 
<renderers> 
<renderer mime="application/pdf"> 
<fonts> 
<auto-detect/> 
</fonts> 
</renderer> 
</renderers> 
</fop>
```

WARNINGS:

> 12 Aug, 2016 4:47:31 PM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent
>   WARNING: Glyph "?" (0xba8) not available in font "Helvetica".
>   12 Aug, 2016 4:47:31 PM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent
>   WARNING: Glyph "?" (0xba9) not available in font "Helvetica".
>   12 Aug, 2016 4:47:31 PM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent
>   WARNING: Glyph "?" (0xbcd) not available in font "Helvetica".
>   12 Aug, 2016 4:47:31 PM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent
>   WARNING: Glyph "?" (0xbb1) not available in font "Helvetica".

Result:
***Sathish ##### Channels 2016***
***Sathish d#koju Channels 2016***
***Sathish ######### Channels 2016***

[Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxX0w.png)

Comment: Isn't it simply this: `WARNING: Glyph "?" (0xbb1) not available in font "Helvetica"`? Which part of that seems unclear to you?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the font configuration. thanks, it works now.

Comment: Can you please specify the solution, What you did in the font configuration and where?
I am facing the same issue . @Sathish